# Proper way to close/dispose of a ServiceHost Thread in C#?

Tags: c#, wcf, servicehost

I am building a very simple server that has to use named pipes in .NET, and will be ran behind a Windows Forms GUI. I have been able to implement a ServiceHost in a 'Server' class (below) and communicate with it using a 'Client' class. The problem I am having is figuring out the proper way to close the ServiceHost that is running on a thread, as well as disposing of the thread when the form is closed. I am new to threads and named pipes, so be nice! 

This is the form which starts my server/client:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    Thread server;
    Client client;

    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        server = new Thread(() => new Server());
        server.Start();

        client = new Client();
        client.Connect();
    }
}

private void MyForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    // Close server thread and disconnect client.
    client.Disconnect();

    // Properly close server connection and dispose of thread(?)
}
```

And here is the Server class:

```
class Server : IDisposable
{
    public ServiceHost host;
    private bool disposed = false;

    public Server()
    {
        host = new ServiceHost(
            typeof(Services),
                new Uri[]{
                new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")
            });

        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServices), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "GetData");
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServices), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "SubmitData");
        host.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Server is available.");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    { 
        if(!this.disposed)
        {
            if(disposing)
            {
                host.Close();
            }

            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    ~Server()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Is using IDisposable a good approach to this, and how do I go about calling Dispose() when I'm finished with my thread?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are making this harder than it needs to be.

1. Don't create a thread to start `ServiceHost`. `ServiceHost` will manage its own threads internally for the service calls. There's no advantage to creating a new thread just to start the `ServiceHost`. Also your client `Connect()` call won't succeed until the `ServiceHost` is initialized and running. So there's required synchronization between `server.Start()` and `client.Connect()`. The new thread isn't saving you anything.
2. Do not do Finalizers in C# unless you have a very good reason. `~Server()` is a bad idea.

So get rid of the `Server` class entirely. The wrapper isn't buying you anything (unless you are doing configuration management that isn't shown in the posted code).

**Create the service host in `MyForm()` and call `host.Close()` in `MyForm_FormClosed()`. Done.**

Comment: Getting rid of the `Server` class makes sense. I originally made the thread because my application was locking up when I tried to call the `ServiceHost` from my `Client` class. I think I may be lacking some understanding of the use of threads. Thanks @ErnieL!

Comment: What about when you don't want the service to be listening? is it safe or "good code" to do `host = null;` ?